# HTTP Status 500 during REST request

Tags: java, rest

I am new to REST web services and trying to learn it.
I have below code which is getting messages stored in oracle table via rest call.

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
@Path ("/messages")
public class messages {
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public List<Message> getMessages (){
    MessageService msg = new MessageService();
    System.out.println(msg.getMessages("vulture9"));
    return msg.getMessages("vulture9");
}
```

and another part of it is

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
@XmlRootElement
public class MessageService {

public MessageService(){
}   
public List getMessages(String username){       
    Connection conn;
    List <Map> msgList = new LinkedList<>();        
    try {
        Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@talon.squadrhino.com:1521:orcl", "oracle", "oracle");
        System.out.println("connection successful");            
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql = "select * from message where author = '" + username +"'";
        ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql); 
        while (res.next()){
            Map <String,String> msg = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            msg.put("username", res.getString("author"));
            msg.put("message", res.getString("message"));
            msgList.add(msg);
        }
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return msgList;     
}
}
```

I am fetching messages stored in database table and trying to get them in XML format. i could not see any error in tomcat log but browser just return

below error

```
HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error
type Status report
message Internal Server Error
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
```

I am not sure where to look for or begin debugging..

Comment: What's not working specifically? Fixing this is going to be very difficult without a stacktrace.

Comment: Error 500 being a server-side error, you should look at the server logs, and your webapp logs .

Comment: as i mentioned tomcat does not show any error at all..

Comment: Even in catalina.out ?

Comment: you probably want to add `jersey` in your tag.

Comment: @Berger yes nothing in catalina.log just

Dec 29, 2015 9:23:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2297 ms
connection successful
[{username=vulture9, message=hello there}]
connection successful

Comment: You need to get your tomcat logging fixed before you can proceed. Add a System.out.println at the beginning of your method that says something like "getMessages called". Then add something at the end that says "end of getMessages". You should see that in one of the tomcat log files. If you see those messages then just add more System.out.println calls so that you can pinpoint where the problem is.

Comment: error is coming while converting to XML, cause when i change MediaType to  TEXT_PLAIN i get the required result, so am i converting to XML correctly?

Comment: add try catch for line `msg.getMessages("vulture9")`. Seems to be some error with database or connection, so it throws exception

Answer (score 0):

try to Add jaxb annotation on your Message class.

```
@XmlElement
public List getMessages(String username){ 
}
```

or simply try

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
@Path ("/messages")
public class messages {
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public String getMessages (){
   String res =" test response ";
    return res ;
}
```

there is one good article for xml conversion and java client: http://entityclass.in/rest/jerseyXML.htm